# Clear and Set Interval on one button for Timer

Tags: reactjs, timer, redux, setinterval, clearinterval

I am building a timer in React/Redux and with one button I would like to first clear the interval and then restart it.

```
process({ getState }, dispatch, done) {
  //clear interval first
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    dispatch(countdownCalc());
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where we initially start onclick

```
setClock = () => {
  const currentdate = new Date().getTime();
  this.setState({date:currentdate})

  this.clockCall = setInterval(() => {
    this.incrementClock();
  }, 1000)

}
```

Where we will increment the clock

```
incrementClock = () => {
var date = new Date();
var n = date.toDateString();
var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
this.setState({date:time})
}
```

When the component unmounts we will clear the interval.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.clockCall)
}
```

Add our button for starting.

```
 <button onClick={() => this.setClock()}> Start </button>
```

You can also make another function

```
clear = () => {
 clearInterval(this.clockCall)
}
```

Another approach is to add state so that you can clear the interval by clicking again and using conditionals to change between which function is called.

```
state={clicked:false}

 setClock = () => {
      const currentdate = new Date().getTime();
      this.setState({date:currentdate, clicked:true})

      this.clockCall = setInterval(() => {
        this.incrementClock();
      }, 1000)

    }

  clear = () => {
     clearInterval(this.clockCall)
     this.setState({clicked:false})
    }

   incrementClock = () => {
    var date = new Date();
    var n = date.toDateString();
    var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    this.setState({date:time})
    }


<button onClick={this.state.clicked ? this.clear() : this.setClock()}> {this.state.clicked ? <div> Clear </div> : <div> start </div>} </button>
```